# Memory usage of imputation with mice in R

Tags: r, memory, out-of-memory, imputation, r-mice

I am currently working on the imputation of 10 large datasets (by first creating a prediction matrix with correlation of 0.3, `dfpred03`) with mice in R and I am having a lot of issues like the following:

```
imptest <- mice(df, m=1, maxit = 1, method='cart',predictorMatrix=dfpred03)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  VAR1 VAR2  VAR3  VAR4Error: cannot allocate vector of size 446 Kb
Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 Mb
```

I understand I will have to make some concessions, but because I am not sure what the bottleneck is I do not really know which concessions to make.

Is there any documentation about how `mice` in `R` uses data?

My most important questions:

1. EDITED: How can I adapt the predictor matrix in order to make the imputation process less memory consuming? I am thinking of setting variables which have both low row and column sums to zero, but then I get left with NA's. Another thing I could do is to remove those variables and other variables with low observations.
2. If I succeed in doing one iteration of a dataset, would that mean that I can increase `maxit` and `m` because the maximum memory usage is in the iteration?
3. Is most memory used because of the amount of predictors or the amount of missingness in observations (and therefore the amount of observations)?
4. More generally, where does the spike in memory usage lie?

Comment: I think that it will take more memory, due to the way r manages matrices and data frame while sorting  calculations, than it will just running the full matrix to completion.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried and I think you are right.. So I guess it would be better to remove parts of the dataset all together (for which there are few predictors or many entries missing)?

Comment: Is there anything else living in memory when you are doing this? If you save all your variable and data in `.rdata( )` then `rm()` EVERYTHING from the environment and use `gc()`. Close all other applications.  It will free up as much memory as possible

Comment: No, everything else is removed, as per your suggestion. That's why I have to figure out other options..